# How do I manage my gitlab private repository after it's been forked?

Tags: git, gitlab, fork

When my private repository is forked by a user, I don't have access to the forked repositories, and I have no way to manage them. Even if I remove the user's permissions from my repository, the forked repository is no longer under my control.

In such cases, Github will help me manage the access of those repositories that have forked from my private repository. I can always remove someone' access to my private repository, and he will no longer have the access to his own forked repository(In fact those forked repositories are deleted). In such way I can protect my intellectual property.

What is Gitlab's policy for managing private repository forks, how do I control the access of my private repository after it's been forked by others?

Comment: "In such way I can protect my intellectual property." Don't count on it. The fork may be deleted from GitHub, but the user's clone of that fork is not going to vanish magically from the user's computer! So the user can just mirror their copy of your repo back up to GitHub. And they are then free to take it public. You may be misunderstanding the purpose and nature of GitHub's private fork policy.

Comment: Have you tried [contacting Gitlab support](https://about.gitlab.com/support/)?

Comment: GitLab does have a setting where you can prevent forks ahead of time (all the caveats re: cloning others have mentioned still apply, of course). If you want to get really protective, you could limit the IP ranges of clones to environments you control on a closed network. But once the repo has been forked and cloned there’s not much you can do from a technical standpoint.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. Also, what GitHub does isn't actually effective, since it's possible to manually clone and reupload a repo to GitHub, which has the same effect as forking it, but without giving you that power.